# Error installing shinyapps

Tags: r, shiny, install.packages

I've been having trouble downloading the shinyapps package on my windows computer. I've updated my versions of R and studio, tried the devtools download `devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')` and I've also tried the manual download of the shinyapps-master.zip (github.com/rstudio/shinyapps/archive/master.zip) and using `install_local()` all to no avail.
Here is the error I get with each method:

```
Installing shinyapps
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/bin/i386/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpma2fl1\devtools10cc1745fe7\shinyapps-master"  \
  --library="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library" --install-tests 

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Command failed (1)
```

After doing the excellent tutorial for shiny I would love to be able to use shinyapps.io but can't so far due to this. Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: If all your packages are up to date `update.packages(ask = FALSE)`, I think this is a bug of devtools (the path to R should be quoted), and you should report it to devtools authors. Please include `library(devtools); sessionInfo()` in your post.

Comment: @Yihui all the paths in that example are quoted, so it must be a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

The app does not like the fact that R is installed in a directory that includes a space. I recommend reinstalling R to a location without a space, e.g. `c:/R/`.

Comment: I do think it is a problem of the app. It looks more like a devtools issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem. I deleted the shinyapp folder first and then the file with that name. All my packages are saved in ~/Documents/R/win-library/3.1 folder on Windows 7 PC as I have not specified the lib folder. Then I installed the shinyapps package again using devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps') command in R. HTH